# My c++ Code is not working for a Graph

Tags: c++, graph

I am writing a code for a graph in c++ but there is some problem. It is not working properly. Please help me what is the problem with it? Its code for a graph which can take inputs for graph from user and each edge in graph has specific weight.
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct edge {
    char src;
    char dest;
    int weight;
};

class Graph {
public:
     vector<edge> edges;
     int size,j=0;

     //Constructor
     Graph(int c) {
     size=c;
     }

     void graphDesign(char s,char d,int w) {
         edges[j].src=s;
         edges[j].dest=d;
         edges[j].weight=w;
         j++;
     }

    void printGraph() {
         for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            cout<<edges[i].src<<"->"<<edges[i].dest<<"  :  
               <<edges[i].weight<<endl;
         }
    }
 };


int main() {

    int e,i,w;
    char s,d;
    cout<<"Enter number of edges of graphs: ";
    cin>>e;
    Graph graph(e);
     for(i=0; i<e; i++) {
        cout<<"Enter source: ";
        cin>>s;
        cout<<"Enter destination: ";
        cin>>d;
        cout<<"Enter weight of the edge: ";
        cin>>w;

        graph.graphDesign(s,d,w);
    }

    graph.printGraph();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Advice -- Do *not* use extraneous variables like `size` to denote the number of entries in a container.   Use what the container gives you, i.e. `vector::size()`.  By using unnecessary variables, you run the risk of bugs occurring due to not updating that variable when the size changes.  Your code is evidence of this -- what is `edges.size()`?  I bet it isn't what you believe it is.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "is not working properly" means?  How is it not working?

Comment: When I enter the values for 1st time its get terminated while it should ask for values for several time and then it should print the all values.

Comment: @MuhammadAfaqRiaz -- There is nothing in your edges vector, but your code assumes there is at least one entry in the `graphDesign` function.  That is wrong.

Comment: for(i=0; i<e; i++)  Check this statement. Let say e =7 then it should ask for 7 times to enter the value. But it asks for only one time and then terminated.

Comment: @MuhammadAfaqRiaz -- There is no `edges[0]`.  It is an illegal access.

Comment: When `edges` is constructed, it is empty.  You don't do anything to change that.

Comment: @MuhammadAfaqRiaz Change your code to do `edges.at(j).whatever = ...` instead of `edges[j].whatever = ...` in the `graphDesign` function.  You should now get a `std::out_of_range` exception thrown.  That would basically confirm what we're saying -- you are accessing an out-of-bounds entry in the vector.

Comment: I suggest you learn how to debug your code. [This blog article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some great tips to help you get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is here:

```
void graphDesign(char s,char d,int w) {
         edges[j].src=s;
         edges[j].dest=d;
         edges[j].weight=w;
         j++;
     }
```

Since `edges` is an empty vector, accessing `edges[j]` is an illegal access.

You need to size the `edges` vector appropriately before you use it.

```
class Graph {
public:
     vector<edge> edges;

     //Constructor
     Graph(int c) : edges(c) {}
```

This creates a vector with `c` entries.

Also, do **not** use extraneous, unnecessary member variables such as `size` here.  The `vector` class has a `size()` member function to tell you how many items are in the container.

Using extraneous variables like `size` runs the risk of bugs occurring due to having to update this variable anytime the vector changes size.  Instead of trying to do this housekeeping yourself, use the `size()` function provided to you by `std::vector`.